# In a Makefile, use patsubst and wildcard with subfolders and subfolder substitutions

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to use a makefile to convert some markdown files to html files.  I'm trying to accomplish in a few lines that which I previously had a long python script doing.

In the simple example below, I would like to see this code:

```
build: $(patsubst src/pages/%.md, output/%.html, $(wildcard src/pages/*.md))

%.html: %.md
    @echo $< to $@
```

and this output

```
src/pages/index.md to output/index.html
src/pages/about.md to output/about.html
src/pages/contact.md to output/contact.html
src/page/foo/bar.md to output/foo/bar.html
```

Instead, it says:

```
$ make build
make: *** No rule to make target 'output/index.html', needed by 'build'.  Stop.
```

I'm missing something very basic here.

Comment: Try `output/%.html: src/pages/%.md`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the target `output/index.html`.  The dependency...

```
%.html: %.md
```

will effectively expand to...

```
output/index.html: output/index.md
```

with `$*` equal to `output/index`.  So `make` looks for `output/index.md` but can't find it -- hence the error message.

To get the correct pattern stem (`$*` == `index`) you need to add the base directories to the pattern rule...

```
output/%.html: src/pages/%.md
    @echo $< to $@
```

**EDIT 1:**

If you're concerned about repeated hard-coded strings such as `output` and `src/pages` then you can always assign them to parameters...

```
OUTPUT_DIR := output
SOURCE_DIR := src/pages

build: $(patsubst $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.md, $(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.html, $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/*.md))


$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.html: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.md
    @echo $< to $@
```

(Assuming that's what you meant by `optimization' in your comment.)

Comment: That works.  Now, I'm wondering about the repeating of the word output and src/pages and such.  Is there an optimization available that can avoid this?